# snap layouts menu doesn't appear on windows 11 for custom maximize button

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-11

My goal is to create a custom maximize button for my app and I also want to trigger snap layouts menu on the button on Windows 11. For that, I am following the guide from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-snap-layout-menu), but it doesn't work.

Here is the sample code, For testing purpose, I take a rectangle {point(0,0), size(200,200)} and when the mouse is over it and I receive WM_NCHITTEST message I return the HTMAXBUTTON as instructed in the guide but the snap layouts menu doesn't show up.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Test Window",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
        );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.

        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;

    case WM_NCHITTEST:
    {
        // Get the point in screen coordinates.
        // GET_X_LPARAM and GET_Y_LPARAM are defined in windowsx.h
        POINT point = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        // Map the point to client coordinates.
        ::MapWindowPoints(nullptr, hwnd, &point, 1);
        RECT maximizeRect {0, 0, 200, 200};
        // If the point is in your maximize button then return HTMAXBUTTON
        if (::PtInRect(&maximizeRect, point))
        {
            printf("maxmize button rect %d\n", rand());
            fflush(stdout);
            return HTMAXBUTTON;
        }

        break;
    }

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning, [custom title bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe#removing-the-standard-frame) before [supporting the snap layouts menu](https://github.com/oberth/custom-chrome/blob/30214eeb02c34d2c330277e81128cc5b73f38b67/source/gui/window_helper.hpp#L17)

1. `maximizeRect` is client coordinates and not the maximize button rectangle.
2. The [WM_NCHITTEST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest) return value is wrong. *If the point is in your maximize button then return HTMAXBUTTON*.

There is a [HitTestNCA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe#appendix-c-hittestnca-function) example which calculates in the screen coordinate instead of the client coordinate and works fine. Another [win32-window-custom-titlebar](https://github.com/grassator/win32-window-custom-titlebar/blob/fec586e8c51271e3f3d2c1e13bd0effbaae952b9/main.c#L266) sample.

Comment: the code I posted is just example, in the real application the painting is done by a different stack, and maximize button can be anywhere

Comment: But you need to [custom title bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe#removing-the-standard-frame) before [supporting the snap layouts menu](https://github.com/oberth/custom-chrome/blob/30214eeb02c34d2c330277e81128cc5b73f38b67/source/gui/window_helper.hpp#L17)

Comment: @unknown.prince Have you checked the linked samples?

Comment: I had to handle WM_NCACLSIZE and remove the native title bar and then the above example works fine.