# Win32 API - custom frame with drawing in a loop - snap layout menu flickers

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I am writing application where I would like to draw entire window with OpenGL, including custom frame with custom minimize/maximize/close buttons. I managed to do that responding to `WM_NCHITTEST` message. However I noticed that snap layout menu is flickering. Popup will initially show up in top-left screen corner for brief moment and only then moves to mouse cursor. I need to draw 60 times per second for smooth animations (so drawing needs to be in the main app loop).

I am talking about this menu:
[image: snap layout menu screenshot]

Does anybody knows what's the reason of snap layout menu flickering and how to fix it?

UPDATE: actually snap layout menu flickers also without OpenGL, drawing in a loop just with Win API produces same flicker.

Full minimal example in C++ code below (without OpenGL:

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Windowsx.h"
#include "dwmapi.h"
#include "math.h"


struct AppState {
  HINSTANCE hInstance;
  HWND hwnd;
  HDC hdc;
  HGLRC hRC;
  float time;
};
static AppState appState = {};

void fill (HDC hdc, RECT r, float color) {
  int c = (int)(color * 255.0f + 0.5f);
  if (c < 0) c = 0;
  if (c > 255) c = 255;
  HBRUSH br = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(c, c, c));
  FillRect(hdc, &r, br);
  DeleteObject(br);
}

void render () {
  PAINTSTRUCT ps;
  HDC hdc = BeginPaint(appState.hwnd, &ps);
  RECT r = {0, 0, 600, 600};
  fill(hdc, r, 0.5f + 0.2f * sinf(appState.time * 0.01f));

  RECT r2 = {450, 450, 600, 600};
  fill(hdc, r2, 0.0f);

  EndPaint(appState.hwnd, &ps);
}

LRESULT __stdcall Wndproc(
  HWND hwnd,
  UINT uMsg,
  WPARAM wParam,
  LPARAM lParam
) {
  switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_NCHITTEST: {
      POINT p = {GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam)};
      ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p);
      // for testing put maximize button in bottom-right corner
      if (p.x >= 450 && p.x < 600 && p.y >= 450 && p.y < 600) {
        return HTMAXBUTTON;
      }
      break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
    case WM_CLOSE: {
      PostQuitMessage(0);
      return 0;
    }
    case WM_NCACTIVATE: {
      return 1;
    }
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE: {
      if (wParam) {
        return WVR_VALIDRECTS;
      }
      return 0; // If the wParam parameter is FALSE, the application should return zero.
    }
    case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
      return 1; // An application should return nonzero if it erases the background
    }
    case WM_SYNCPAINT:
    case WM_NCPAINT: {
      return 0;
    }
    case WM_PAINT: {
      render();
      return 0;
    }
  }
  LRESULT dwmRes;
  if (DwmDefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam, &dwmRes)) {
    return dwmRes;
  }

  return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


static bool createWindow (int nCmdShow) {
  const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"TestClass";
  const wchar_t TITLE[] = L"Title";
  SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);

  WNDCLASSEXW wc = {};
  wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
  wc.style = CS_OWNDC;// | CS_DROPSHADOW; // NOTE: not using CS_VREDRAW as we render ourselves
  wc.lpfnWndProc = Wndproc;
  wc.hInstance = appState.hInstance;
  wc.hIcon = LoadIconW(NULL, (LPCWSTR)IDI_APPLICATION);
  wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
  if (RegisterClassExW(&wc) == 0) {
    return false;
  }
  // WS_THICKFRAME: without this the window cannot be resized and so aero snap, de-maximizing and minimizing won't work
  // WS_SYSMENU: enables the context menu with the move, close, maximize, minize... commands (shift + right-click on the task bar item)
  // WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, WS_MINIMIZEBOX: enable minimize/maximize in context menu
  // WS_CAPTION: enables aero minimize animation/transition
  DWORD style = WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
  if (false) {
    style |= WS_CAPTION; // can't have fullscreen while maximized, but has animations
  }
  appState.hwnd = CreateWindowExW(
    WS_EX_APPWINDOW, CLASS_NAME, TITLE, style,
    500, 500, 600, 600, // x, y, w, h
    0, 0, appState.hInstance, 0
  );
  if (appState.hwnd == 0) {
    return false;
  }

  ShowWindow(appState.hwnd, nCmdShow);
  return true;
}


// returns true when need to exit
bool processMessages () {
  MSG message;
  while (PeekMessageW(&message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
    if (message.message == WM_QUIT) {
      return true;
    }
    TranslateMessage(&message);
    DispatchMessageW(&message);
  }
  return false;
}



int __stdcall wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, wchar_t* pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
  appState.hInstance = hInstance;

  if (!createWindow(nCmdShow)) {
    return 1;
  }
  for (;;) {
    if (processMessages()) {
      break;
    }
    // need to draw 60 times per second for smooth animation
    InvalidateRect(appState.hwnd, 0, 0);

    // hacky way for demo only
    Sleep(16);
    appState.time += 16.0f;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I said in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74650307/15511041), you need to [custom title bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe#removing-the-standard-frame) before [supporting the snap layouts menu](https://github.com/oberth/custom-chrome/blob/30214eeb02c34d2c330277e81128cc5b73f38b67/source/gui/window_helper.hpp#L17). Apart from examples mentioned in that answer, [the custom-chrome example](https://github.com/oberth/custom-chrome) is tested and also works fine.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Do you mean to use DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea? I just tried it (with margins = {-1}) and it did not help. Custom-chrome example does rendering inside WM_PAINT, but I need to draw in main loop for real-time 3D graphics. If I move rending to WM_PAINT, then no flicker is happening, but then I can't do real-time animation.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I also tried to do rendering in WM_PAINT and putting `InvalidateRect` inside main loop, which again results in snap layouts flickering.

Comment: As [Enabling Hit Testing for the Custom Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe#enabling-hit-testing-for-the-custom-frame) said, *To properly hit test the caption buttons in custom frame scenarios, messages should first be passed to DwmDefWindowProc for handling.* You'd better have a try for [the document sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe#appendix-a-sample-window-procedure).

Comment: And could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without OpenGL?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Problem is that without OpenGL it works, and all examples without it work too. DwmDefWindowProc also I have tried without any change in behavior. It looks that rendering in the loop somehow messes up DWM. Mine example is full - you don't need any 3rd party libraries to compile, just Visual Studio. I will try rendering with win32 api only.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT I just added example without OpenGL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253671/discussion-between-somnium-and-yangxiaopo-msft).